# Avoid operator>> to break input at whitespaces

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

I'm overloading the `operator>>` function. It should take a string in input, with some whitespaces needed, explode the string at whitespaces and do other operations not relevant for the topic.

I have this code:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Foo &f) {
    std::string str;
    in >> str;
    std::cout << "str = " << str << std::endl; // for testing
    // ...
    return in;
}
```

Assuming to put this string (a complex number) as input:

```
3 + 2i
```

the `std::cout` function prints only `3`. I tried to put the flag `std::noskipws`, but the problem is still there.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) function to read complete input line:

```
std::getline(in, str);
```